# What is the schema for Hbase to load Json data

Tags: json, hadoop, hbase

What is the schema for HBase table to load json data. I have json data as below

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "Katerina",
        "languages": [
                { "lang":"en" , "knowledge":"proficient" },
                { "lang":"fr" , "knowledge":"advanced" },
        ]
        "job":{
                "site":"www.javacodegeeks.com",
                "name":"Java Code Geeks",
        }
        religions":{"catholic":[10,20],"protestant":[40,50]}
}
```

And I have created HBase table with column families but Im not able to load the json data

```
create  'test_json','id','firstname','languages','job','religions'
```

Comment: HBase allows you to store and retrieve bytes. There is no support for any other data type. To store json file, serialize it to bytes and store them. If you need to store json fields in separate columns, consider implementing this on the client side. Alternatively, you might want to look at Avro as a way of serializing your objects to reduce the amount of data being stored.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your json into string and then store as bytes. But remember, you ill loose the ability to search as you data has to be unmarshalled before fitting into any kind of query options. HBase works best, when you stick to key-value type data and when you have dynamic or unknown or irregular columns for each row. The above way of storing is ok if you are trying to store nested entities, in the same row. It depends on the way you want your date to be retrieved